# Delete the output of find

Tags: command-line, delete, grep, find

I installed app called zoom and it somehow stopped working. I tried reinstalling it but still wouldn't work. I'm trying to delete any files related to the application.

I tried

```
find / * | grep "zoom"
```

Is there a way i can delete files shown by this command

Answer (score 6):

Your `find` command is silly. How did you install `zoom`? If via `synaptic`, `apt`, `apt-get` or any other installer that respects the Ubuntu packaging system, you may see the files with

```
dpkg -L zoom
```

and remove it (and not confuse the packaging system) with

```
sudo apt purge zoom
```

If you insist on using `find`, re-read `man find`, and do something like

```
sudo find / -iname 'zoom*'
```

or (read `man xargs`)

```
sudo find / -type f -iname 'zoom*' -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm
```

to delete all the files whose names start with `zoom`. Remove the `echo` word when you are happy with the generated file list.

Comment: Or `-delete`, so that you can delete the directories as well.